# Interpretation of multiple logistic regression with interactions in R

Tags: r, regression, logistic, interaction, interpretation

I am trying to look at whether 2 variables (one dichotomous categorical and one continuous) predict the occurrence of a dichotomous categorical dependent variable.

```
dependent variable is LENIpos - 0 = no event, 1 = event
predictor variables are Hip.Prox.Femur - 0 = no hip fracture, 1 = hip fracture
                and     age (continuous)
```

Both predictor variables have significant p values in separate chi square test and Mann Whitney U test respectively.

When I run a logistic regression `glm(LENIpos ~ age + Hip.Prox.Femur, family = "binomial)`, the variables come out as not significant. (1)

However, when I run the logistic regression with interactions `glm(LENIpos ~ age * Hip.Prox.Femur...)` (2), they are no both significant.  How is this to be interpreted?

Example R outputs:

(1)

```
Call: glm(formula = LENIpos ~ age + Hip.Prox.Fem, family = "binomial", 
    data = dvt)

Deviance Residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
 -0.9346  -0.7826  -0.4952  -0.3374   2.1897  

Coefficients:
                         Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   
(Intercept)              -3.46888    1.00693  -3.445 0.000571 ***
age                       0.02122    0.01519   1.397 0.162535  
Hip.Prox.Femhip fracture  0.72410    0.57790   1.253 0.210212    

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 145.23  on 151  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 135.48  on 149  degrees of freedom
AIC: 141.48

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5
```

(2)

```
glm(formula = LENIpos ~ age * Hip.Prox.Fem, family = "binomial", 
    data = dvt)

Deviance Residuals: 
        Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
    -1.0364  -0.7815  -0.5373  -0.1761   2.3443  

Coefficients:
                             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept)                  -5.89984    1.98289  -2.975  0.00293 **
age                           0.05851    0.02818   2.076  0.03788 * 
Hip.Prox.Femhip fracture      5.04990    2.46269   2.051  0.04031 * 
age:Hip.Prox.Femhip fracture -0.06058    0.03339  -1.814  0.06965 . 


(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 145.23  on 151  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 131.82  on 148  degrees of freedom
AIC: 139.82

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 6
```

Comment: General advice: 1) plot your data several different ways, 2) calculate confidence intervals and interpret their substantive significance rather than merely focusing on whether a coefficient attains statistical significance at some arbitrary (.1/.05/.01) level.

Answer (score 6):

The relation of `age` or `Hip.Prox.Femhip` to the probability of `LENIpos` depends on the value of the other variable. That is suggested by the interaction term in your second model. In the usual R presentaton of regression coefficients, the coefficient for `age` in the second model is the relation of `LENIpos` to `age` in the absence of fracture, and the interaction term (`age:Hip.Prox.Femhip fracture`) is the *difference* from that relation in the presence of fracture. So the data seem consistent with age having a relation to`LENIpos` in the absence of fracture, but not in the presence of fracture. Plots of the +/- fracture subsets should help clarify this.

Answer (score 4):

@EdM is right.  The fact that the interaction's p-value is .06 (i.e., 'not-significant') is meaningless; you have an interaction.  Let me add a few more details to supplement his (?) answer:

- A Mann-Whitney U-test of `age~LENIpos` isn't really the same as the univariate logistic regression of `LENIpos~age` (although the p-values will almost always be both significant or both not).  You would do better to assess the univariate association by running the logistic regression.
- In R, a multiple linear regression comes with a global F-test of the model by default, but a multiple logistic regression does not (unfortunately).  However, you can get a global test by assessing the difference between the null and residual deviances against a chi-squared distribution with the degrees of freedom equal to the difference between the null and residual dfs.  Here is the test for your first model:

  ```
  > pchisq(q=145.23-135.48, df=151-149, lower.tail=FALSE)
  [1] 0.007635094
  ```

  So it is clear that your first model is significant.
- This seeming paradox (both univariate analyses significant, and the two predictor model significant even though neither predictor itself is significant) has a hidden cause:  Your two predictors are themselves correlated.  (The general name for this is [multicollinearity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicollinearity).)  As a result, the model doesn't know which of the two to attribute the association and expands both standard errors to acknowledge this fact.

  *(Note that the preceding discussion ignores the existence of the interaction.)*

---

- As @EdM states, plotting these functions can help you understand the interaction.  Here is a basic plot with your output:

  ```
  lo.to.p = function(lo){
    odds = exp(lo)
    prob = odds / (odds+1)
    return(prob)
  }
  age   = 0:80
  lo.no =  -5.89984 + 0.05851*age
  lo.fr = (-5.89984 + 5.04990) + (0.05851 + -0.06058)*age
  p.no  = lo.to.p(lo.no)
  p.fr  = lo.to.p(lo.fr)

  windows()
    plot( age, p.no, col="blue", type="l", ylim=c(0,1), ylab="probability of LENIpos")
    lines(age, p.fr, col="red")
    legend("topleft", legend=c("no fracture", "fracture"), lty=1, col=c("blue","red"))
  ```

[image]

Comment: EdM sends his thanks for this elaboration on his answer.